# I am trying to index dataset by date, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

I have this data in my DataFrame: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNPJw.png)

I keep getting this error:

```
Key error 'Date'
```

When I type this command:

```
df1['Date']
```

I inserted my data set, but Python wont let me see just the dates. I want to turn Daily data into quarterly.

Comment: It means what it sounds like: your data set does not have dates in it to show you.

Comment: It does have dates though, I can see them when I do df.tail()

Comment: Show us the data and ask the question

Comment: Picture added to original post

Comment: df1['DATE'] to see the date

Comment: The column names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the help

Comment: @jimmy2891 do u want to make date as index ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make your data to quarterly first you need to convert your date `to_datetime`.

(Unless you did that when reading the data in `read_csv`)

`df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE])`

Then you might want to put your date as index.

Secondly you need to resample your data.

`df1.resample("Q")` for quarterly

Answer (score -1):

Your column name is in upper case : "DATE".

So you should try this instead:

```py
df1['DATE']
```